# Is there an emerging standard API for NoSQL Databases?

Tags: nosql, standards

I was wondering if there are any standard languages or API's for accessing NoSQL databases (or at least BigData or Column store) databases?

Or do you have to learn the domain specific language for each vendor's contribution?

Comment: I hope people won't close this question. I really just want to know if there are any unified API's? Not sure why that would be considered contentious?

Comment: As in, database agnostic abstraction layers like PDO for PHP? I'm not sure what the standard for NoSQL would be, except 'Not SQL'.

Comment: I may be missing the point of Stack Overflow - why is this question controversial, and is there a better forum for this inquiry? I am trying to research NoSQL for an article, and I think this is a very relevant question.

Comment: Yes I think this is a relevant question, I don't know why some people are so like that...

Comment: Anyway, until now I haven't really seen any "standard" NoSQL language by which vendors do implement. Maybe we can just look at the most popular NoSQL (like MongoDB) and say that that's where everybody is going. Much like Amazon S3 for object storage; where it has become a standard because many copy their interface...

Answer (score 3):

One potentially interesting one is [AppScale](http://appscale.cs.ucsb.edu/datastores.html) which provides a unified API for HBase, Hypertable, MySQL Cluster, Cassandra, Voldemort, MongoDB, MemcacheDB and Redis. The API is defined by Google for the Google App Engine and is available for [Java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/), [Python](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/) and [Go](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/).

Comment: Oh, and if you're using the Google App Engine API in Java, you should look at Objectify https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/

Answer (score 2):

Relational database have the SQL language.

NoSQL databases are of different types: graph, columns, document. key value, etc.

They are all specific to handle. Maybe one type could have a unified language, but between them, that would be not so natural. So yes you have to use/learn the API for each type.

At another level, if you use java as a programming language, you may use spring data which proposes a set of libraries to access those databases. I did not use it but with it you will be able to compare the APIs between the different database types quite easily.

Then you have this question that seems well related to yours: [Are there any NoSQL standards emerging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439878/are-there-any-nosql-standards-emerging)

Comment: It makes sense that Graph databases would not have the same API as Columnar, but what about HBase vs. Cassandra?

Answer (score 2):

I saw 2 initiatives whose goal is to provide a unified interface to all NoSQL DB's.
One is [UnQL](http://www.unqlspec.org/display/UnQL/Home) which provides a very SQL DML-like interface.

The other is [Apache Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/), which provide a language-neutral way to describe and implement queries.